# Using variable variable names to access global.arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is what I do today

```
    if (slot=="BARDAY") {
        adActiveTable = global.ad_BARDAY[0];
    } else if (slot=="FRONT") {
        adActiveTable = global.ad_FRONT[0];
    } else if (slot=="RIGHT") {
        adActiveTable = global.ad_RIGHT[0];
    } else if (slot=="TOPLIST") {
        adActiveTable = global.ad_TOPLIST[0];
    }
```

(etc... I got a LOT of them)

My queston is, why doesnt this work?

```
    adActiveTable = global.ad_[slot][0];
```

(that solution gives "Cannot read property 'FRONT' of undefined" if e.g. the slot is = "FRONT")

I even tried this

```
    adActiveTable = global.ad_[slot];
```

And still same error??

Is there no better way to do this?
(no eval() please) :-)

Comment: `global['ad_' + slot][0]`.

Comment: let ne try right away

Comment: global.ad_[slot][0]` this means `global` has a property called `.ad_` which is of time object. You are trying to fetch value for key stored in `slot` which is an array. And finally fetching its first item

Comment: global['ad_' + slot][0] worked perfectly - I kept using the "global dot" and kept getting errors.  Thank you @Tushar

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24514304/3783478) in marked dupe addresses the situation in this post